# Fancybox jQuery: iframe vs ajax

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Can someone explain the difference between loading content into Fancybox via iframe vs Ajax?

Also, is it possible to have a gallery (e.g. rel="gallery") with either iframed or Ajax'ed content?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `iframe` mode, the opened page works as a totally separated and independent page from the calling page and it may have its own structure, functionality and styles. You could skip to open the page in fancybox and open it in a new window/tab.

On the other hand, using `ajax` mode, the opened content becomes part of the calling page DOM structure (normally as a html element like a `<div>`) and can inherit the styles, functionality and properties of the calling page.

Regarding :

```
is it possible to have a gallery (e.g. rel="gallery") with either 
iframed or Ajax'ed content?
```

... the answer is **yes**. You could combine **in the same** fancybox gallery, images, swf objects, inline content (from a hidden `<div>`), youtube videos, ajax content, iframed pages, pdf documents and hard-coded custom content inside the script.

Here [is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/VNPzA/) of a gallery that combines images and youtube videos.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. With respect to the second part, I guess it's not possible to have the gallery working if anchors are not used. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/skube/8apMv/1/)

Comment: Although, I do notice I can navigate next/prev when I don't initiate the fancybox from the first (non-anchor) link.

Comment: @skube : if you want to use elements other than anchors, then use the `data-fancybox-group` attribute instead of `rel` in all elements including any anchor that may be part of the same gallery.