# Fancybox works just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I working in code where they use fancybox to bring up a form.

It works just as it should at first time, in second time, the background site dispose ( because of the applied theme ), but the Fancybox does not load.

This code is used to initialize the Fancybox.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: 'ajax',
    onCleanup: function() {
      var myContent = this.href;
      $(myContent).unwrap();
      console.log("Element was clean");
    }
  });
});
```

I did add this console.log to check when onCleanup is been called, but it never does.

Comment: `onCleanup` is an API option for v1.3.x not available in fancybox v2.x .... in that case use `beforeClose`. Anyways, my guess is that the page you are loading (via ajax) is loading something (a script or a duplicated js like jQuery) that triggers a js error and prevents fancybox from working. Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821699/1055987 if that helps

Comment: @JFK Just changing to beforeClose worked to me. Don't you like to post as a answer?